# I came across this in my sever. What does this do?

Tags: php

I came across this in my sever. And I was wondering what these PHP codes do.

```
<?php
    $request_method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    if($request_method == "GET"){
      $query_vars = $_GET;
    } elseif ($request_method == "POST"){
      $query_vars = $_POST;
    }
    reset($query_vars);
    $t = date("U");

    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../data/gdform_" . $t;
    $fp = fopen($file,"w");
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($query_vars)) {
     fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key START>\n");
     fputs($fp,"$val\n");
     fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key END>\n");
     if ($key == "redirect") { $landing_page = $val;}
    }
    fclose($fp);
    if ($landing_page != ""){
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/$landing_page");
    } else {
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/");
    }


?>
```

All I see is headering me to the a new destination?

Comment: ...that and creating some sort of GDFORM file, whatever that is :)

Comment: "headering" is quite an interesting neologism :)

Comment: learn `PHP` basics after that you will know what this code do.

Comment: Can you read code? If yes, what exactly is it that you do not understand?

Comment: And you didn't notice the `fputs()` at all?

Comment: It sends you to a location with `header` and it saves either the `POST` or the `GET` to a file-per-day. But really, it's not that hard to understand, is it? DId you look up the various functions? What did you find? What got you in trouble understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stores all data sent by GET or POST to a file (a GDFORM-file, whatever that is) and then redirects the user to a specific page. So I'm guessing it's a log function of some sort.

It might be interesting to look through the files though, since login credentials and such would be stored along with other form/get-data.